# gcc changes address of mapped variable during optimization

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, linker, memory-mapping

I'm compiling C code for ARM stm32 microcontroller using arm-none-eabi-gcc v4.9.3 in an open source environment.
The code runs fine without compiler optimizations (gcc -g -O0 ...).

When I enable even slightest optimizations (gcc -g -O1 ...), the address of linker defined variables are changed.

file memory.ld

```
register_cortexm3_ACTLR      = 0xe000e008;
...

MEMORY
{
                 rom (rx ) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000,  LENGTH = 256K
                 ram (rxw) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,  LENGTH = 64K
        sram_bitband (rw ) : ORIGIN = 0x22000000,  LENGTH = 32768K
          peripheral (rw ) : ORIGIN = 0x40000000,  LENGTH = 1024K
  peripheral_bitband (rw ) : ORIGIN = 0x42000000,  LENGTH = 32768K
                sram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x60000000,  LENGTH = 1048576K
        ram_external (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x60000000,  LENGTH = 1048576K
                code (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x60000000,  LENGTH = 1048576K
     device_external (rw ) : ORIGIN = 0xa0000000,  LENGTH = 1048576K
  private_peripheral (rw ) : ORIGIN = 0xe0000000,  LENGTH = 1024K
       vendor_memory (rw ) : ORIGIN = 0xe0100000,  LENGTH = 523264K
}

SECTIONS
{
 /* Section for variables mapped onto registers */
 .peripherals (OVERLAY) :
 {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.peripherals)
 } >peripheral

 .private_peripherals (OVERLAY) :
 {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.private_peripherals)
} >private_peripheral

...
```

file register_cortexm3.h

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned DISMCYCINT  : 1;
    unsigned DISDEFWBUF  : 1;
    unsigned DISFOLD     : 1;
    unsigned reserved1   : 13;
    unsigned reserved2   : 16;
} __attribute__( ( __packed__ ) ) register_cortexm3_actlr_t;

...
```

file register_cortexm3.c

```
void check_same( volatile void* Address1, volatile void* Address2 ) {

    if ( Address1 != Address2 )
    { Assert_Halt_EC( ec_InvalidImplementation ); }
}

volatile register_cortexm3_actlr_t register_cortexm3_ACTLR   
__attribute__( ( section( ".private_peripherals" ) ) ); 

void register_cortexm3_prepare() {

    // checking for correct linker script settings
    check_same(&( register_cortexm3_ACTLR ), ( volatile void* ) 0xe000e008);
}
```

---

When optimizations are enabled, the above comparison fails because inside the check_same() function, the first argument is 0xe0000000 (the start address of its memory section) according to gdb:

```
Breakpoint 1, Assert_Halt_EC   (ErrorCode=ErrorCode@entry=ec_InvalidImplementation) at ttc-lib/ttc_basic.c:65
65      void Assert_Halt_EC( volatile ErrorCode_e ErrorCode ) { // block endless
(gdb) up
#1  0x08004440 in check_same (Address1=Address1@entry=0xe0000000, Address2=Address2@entry=0xe000e008) at ttc-lib/ttc_basic.c:58
58          { Assert_Halt_EC( ec_InvalidImplementation ); }
(gdb) up
#2  0x080034f6 in register_cortexm3_prepare () at ttc-lib/register/register_cortexm3.c:40
40          Assert_SameAddress( &( register_cortexm3_ACTLR ), ( void* ) 0xe000e008 );
(gdb) x &( register_cortexm3_ACTLR )
0xe000e008:     0x00000000
```

As you can see in the last gdb output line, gdb knows the correct address of register_cortexm3_ACTLR.

Is this a gcc bug or a feature?
How to work around it?

Comment: Where is it defined that register_cortexm3 should be at 0xe000e008?

Comment: At first line of memory.ld, right before ...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why optimization would any affect on this but the basic problem is that you've given two different and conflicting definitions of the  symbol `register_cortexm3_ACTLR`. One definition, in your linker script, says that it's at address 0xe000e008 in no section, while the other, in your C code, says that it's at some offset of the `.private_peripherals` section.

You need to choose one of the other. If you want the variable at the address given in linker script, use an `extern` to reference it. Something like:

```
extern volatile register_cortexm3_actlr_t register_cortexm3_ACTLR;
```

Comment: This works! It now runs with -O1 .. -O9! :-)
I always thought that I have to declare a variable outside of RAM and then move it via linker script to specific location.

Comment: @Gregor You can't use a linker script to move individual variables, you can only move sections.

Comment: When I don't enable compile optimizations, then I can! ;-)
In fact, I had an extern declaration in the header file in addition to the variable declaration in the c-file. So the question should be: Why did it work with disabled optimizations?

Comment: @Gregor It didn't actually move the variable, it's just picked a different definition of the symbol to use. The variable you declared in the C code is still taking up space at some offset in the `.private_peripherals` section. Another possibility is that the C variable just happened to end up at the correct address without optimization. That would require that you have other variables defined in `.private_peripherals` and optimization changed the order that the compiler emitted these variables.

Answer (score 0):

To put it all together. This is how one can map a variable to a fixed address instead of using a pointer variable.

Advantages of mapped variables over pointers:
- no RAM usage (each pointer consumes 4 bytes in 32-bit architecture)
- no pointer dereferencing for register access (one less memory access)
- no initialization code (pointer has to be inialized)

Let's assume we want a variable u32_t register_Foo mapped to address 0x12345678.
Add a line to your linker script (here memory.ld):

memory.ld

```
register_Foo = 0x12345678;
```

Add a register struct and an extern declaration in your header file.

foo.h

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned DISMCYCINT  : 1;
    unsigned DISDEFWBUF  : 1;
    unsigned DISFOLD     : 1;
    unsigned reserved1   : 13;
    unsigned reserved2   : 16;
} __attribute__( ( __packed__ ) ) register_foo_t;

extern volatile register_foo_t register_Foo;
```

Access your register in your source code.

foo.c

```
#include "foo.h"

void foo() {
    register_Foo.DISFOLD = 1;
    ...
}
```

Thanx for getting this clear.

Comment: With optimization enabled, the compiler will generate the same code for `static register_foo_t volatile * const register_foo_ptr = (register_foo_t *) 0x12345678; ...; register_foo_ptr->DISFOLD = 1` as `register_foo.DISFOLD = 1`. There's no extra RAM usage or initialization because the static variable definition gets optimized way.

Comment: So there is no advantage over static pointer variables at all?

Comment: You can type `.` instead `->`, and it may be preferable to have the addresses defined in one place in the linker script rather than spread out in various C header files. It's also not dependent on optimization.